# Postback causes "Connection has been reset" when page has been left for 10 minutes

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, connection

I don't know if this belongs here or not so apologies if it doesn't.

I am using IIS7, ASP.NET 2.0.

On my development server (and sometimes on my test server) if I leave a page sat still for more than 10 minutes then try to perform a postback (via a button on the page) the page will try and load for 30-60 seconds and then come back with `The connection was reset` message.

I haven't posted any code because it doesn't seem to be a specific page causing the problem.

It's as if the website process has been recyled and the website can't find / establish a link to a new one.

Does anyone have any ideas on where I should start looking either in the code or on the server?

EDIT: Looking at my event logs doesn't show any issue with Exceeded length. It does however come up with a timeout error but I don't know what is causing it to time out.

Comment: did you see this : http://siderite.blogspot.com/2007/08/aspnet-connection-to-server-has-been.html, may be its a help

Comment: This would make sense. I will investigate and try the resolution and post back. Thanks.

Comment: Check to see if you have anything that is close the connections to your database and then the restart of it make the page fails. Also check the size of the viewstate, check if on your pool have limits that make it restart. Is very possible a restart of something on your code to need a second call to make it work, because the first call is need values from the restart.

Comment: I have see the problem of the big viewstate, but on every call-post back.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the request size is greater than the value you have provided. Change the maxRequestLength in the httpRuntime section of the system.web config section of your web.config to accept greater values.

```
<System.Web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8192" />
```